# Check if 'this' checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How can I work out if 'this' checkbox has been checked using the this command?

I have the following but not sure how to implement this (so it only checks the single checkbox selected rather than all on the page

```
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What about this?

```
if($(this).is(':checked'))
```

Comment: This works, but it is not good practice. See my answer for why this is very inefficient.

Answer (score 16):

Presumably you mean `this` in the context of an event handler... In which case, just test the `checked` property:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        // checkbox clicked is now checked
    }
});
```

Note that you can do the same with the following methods:

- `$(this).is(':checked')`
- `$(this).prop('checked')`

However, `this.checked` avoids creating a new jQuery object, so is far more efficient (and quicker to code). `is` is the slowest: it takes twice as long as `prop` and approximately 100 times as long as the simple property lookup.

[jsPerf comparison between this techniques](http://jsperf.com/quickest-way-to-test-if-a-checkbox-is-checked)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the ID selector. The input[type="checkbox"] selector will return 'all checkboxes.

```
if ($('#Checkbox1').is(':checked'))
```

where Checkbox1 is the ID of the checkbox

Answer (score 3):

Look into `prop()`: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

The docs provide multiple of better ways to check for a "checked" checkbox.

```
elem.checked                      |  true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
$(elem).prop("checked")           |  true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state
elem.getAttribute("checked")      |  "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6)      |  "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change
$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6.1+)   |  "checked" (String) Will change with checkbox state
$(elem).attr("checked")(pre-1.6)  |  true (Boolean) Changed with checkbox state
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean like this (0 is index):

```
if ($(':checkbox').get(0).is(':checked'))
```

Or like this:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following, where you know the id

```
$('#edit-checkbox-id').is(':checked');
```

or if you are already refering to the item with this keyword

```
$(this).is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

this example returns all the checkbox was checked